# Google Sheet: filter 1 column base on another column

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 columns.
Column A contains a list of emails.
Column B contains a list of domains.
I want to find any emails that have domain name in column B, and show the results email list in column C.
Is is possible to do this in Google Sheet?

I want to find any emails that have domain name in column B, and show the results email list in column C

Answer (score 0):

I have  developed a custom Google Apps Script function that should address your requirement. Here's how to use it:
Open your Google Sheet.
Navigate to the "Extensions" menu and select "Apps Script."
Paste the provided script into the script editor.
Save the script and run the function "filterEmailsByDomain."
This script will analyze the data in Columns A and B, identifying emails with domains from Column B, and then display the results in Column C.

Feel free to reach out if you have any questions or need further assistance!

```
function filterEmailsByDomain() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    
    var data = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-1, 2).getValues();
    
    var result = data.filter(function(row) {
        var email = row[0];
        var domain = row[1];
        return email.indexOf(domain) !== -1;
    }).map(function(row) {
        return [row[0]];
    });

    sheet.getRange(2, 3, result.length, 1).setValues(result);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Easy with `QUERY`:

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"SELECT A WHERE B is not null")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is what you're asking for:

```
=FILTER(A2:A,COUNTIF(B2:B,A2:A))
```